# event listener not responding to change (oninput) event

Tags: javascript, events, listener

My event listener was not listening to input's value change (I used "oninput" event listener). I tried to console it log, nothing happened, it did not register any change. I tried to find a solution on the internet, and everybody told me that that is the right way to do it. That did not work.

On w3resources I found this:
"(oninput)This event is similar to the onchange event. The difference is that the oninput event occurs immediately after the value of an element has changed, while onchange occurs when the element loses focus, after the content has been changed."

Ok, I was surprised, because my function was not working, so I tried to do the most intuitive thing use "input" instead. And it worked. I am just interested in what is actually going on.

my HTML:

```
<input id="top-right" type="number">
```

my working JS

```
const topRight = document.getElementById("top-right");

topRight.addEventListener("input", function () {
  console.log(topRight.value);
})
```

Js that does not work:

```
topRight.addEventListener("oninput", function () {
  console.log(topRight.value);
})
```

Is it something mysterious or am I just not understanding something elementary?

Comment: *"Is it something mysterious or am I just not understanding something elementary?"* The latter. :-) The event name is `input`, not `oninput`. The "on" prefix is used for the property name (`topRight.oninput = ...`), but not for the event name you pass `addEventListener`.

Comment: Ok, my bad, thanks!